# Get number of rows from query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to make a sheet where I always have to get the last score of a player.

But I can't use the offset to get the last row because I don't know the number of rows from the query result. I don't know if there is a way to use `CountA`, I couldn't use it!

This is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SZAbTUiGsUhTbKVPF9lGZzJhMPqCCMp1VQ0F-Q4zXcw/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying this query:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$D2; "select D where B='" & $B2 &"' and C='"& $C2 &"' ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({$A$2:$D6\ ROW($A$2:$A6)}; 
 "select Col4 
  where Col2='" & $B6 &"' 
    and Col3='"& $C6 &"' 
  order by Col5 desc 
  limit 1"; 0))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 B2:B&C2:C&COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C; B2:B&C2:C; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(C2:C)); {
 B2:B&C2:C&COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C; B2:B&C2:C; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(C2:C))+1\ 
 D2:D}; 2; 0); D2:D))
```

[image]

Comment: Player0, thanks for your help but i made a mistake, i need to take the last SCORE, not the current ! Unfortunately i cant post an image, but i update the sheet. This time i ignored Column C. Thanks sir.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SZAbTUiGsUhTbKVPF9lGZzJhMPqCCMp1VQ0F-Q4zXcw/edit#gid=0

Please, do you have any book about google sheet functions use or you are a developer ? thanks.

Comment: Player0, using the last tip from who delete his comment i did, take a look please. This is the last query:

'=IFERROR( QUERY($A$1:$D1;"select D where B='"&B2&"' offset " & countif($A$1:$A2;$A2)-2;0); $D2)

I had to use the IFERROR because the first line will return the String Column Name, is there another why ? i was thinking about to check if the prior line IsNumber... i dont know.

here is the last sheet, working: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCrb988iEYpMEMuFrkJ2o46_9AAAxr0AFUy5oVPbOXI/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: @EricRakim answer updated. see J2 in your sheet